# Why can't I get a Twitch bearer token with scope "moderator:read:chatters" via URL but I can with the CLI?

Tags: twitch-api

1. I have moderator privileges within the target channel
2. I can get any other scope, such as `moderator:manage:announcements`
3. I can get a valid bearer token with scope=`moderator:read:chatters` via the CLI using
   `twitch token -u -s 'moderator:read:chatters'`, which then works fine for other encoded-URL requests that require the scope, such as `Get Chatters`

However,
https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000&scope=moderator%3Aread%3Achatters does not work (I am using my actual client ID when I try it), and results in:

[image: This site can't be reached]

Is this something to do with this particular endpoint, possibly related to it being in beta, per [the documentation](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-chatters)?

Comment: Does localhost work?

Comment: Every other request (using this exact url but with different scopes) works totally find with localhost.

Comment: Is `response_type=code` correct? shouldn't it be `response_type=token`? https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/irc/authenticate-bot

Comment: Well...you helped me find the answer to my problem! The first issue was that I wasn't getting the authorization page like I was getting for any other scope...but I WAS getting the TOKEN in the URL to which I was redirected, despite the "refused to connect" error  (I hadn't considered that the token/code would be in the URL). The second issue, was, as you pointed-out, it should be type=code, not type=token. Now, the URL the page lands on contains the needed bearer token. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found the issue: nothing was wrong, the page was just behaving differently (redirecting directly to the "refused to connect" page instead of presenting the auth screen first) **because I authorized that scope with the [CLI](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/cli/token-command) already**.